# after install magento 2.4.2 fronend and backend not working properly

Tags: magento2.4.2, php-7.4

I have installed Magento 2.4.2 in ubuntu, but after the installation process when I run the front and backend URL, it's not working properly,

I have installed Magento 2.4.2 using the command line.

PHP 7.4 version,

[image]

[image]

please help me with this issue,
I have tried everything possible ways but it's not resolved yet.
thanks.

Comment: Check module rewrite enabled or not.

Comment: open 404 error link in new tab and remove "verson161476..." slug and check it's working in new tab or not

Answer (score 2):

Run below commands :

1. sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
2. sudo php bin/magento c:c

Comment: i have run all command 3 times but no changes are done.

Comment: even i checked permission also, all persmissions are correct

Comment: Try sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade
sudo php bin/magento c:f

Answer (score 0):

Try to run below commands:

```
sudo php bin/magento sampledata:reset
sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade
sudo php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your webserver document root is configured correctly. It should be serving Magento from `magento_root_folder/pub`.

For more information see the following official documentation:

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/tutorials/change-docroot-to-pub.html

Answer (score 0):

1. symlink

Create symlink of pub/media and pub/static directory in root.

ln -s /{path}/pub/media /{path}/media

ln -s /{path}/pub/static /{path}/static

example:

ln -s /var/www/html/m242/pub/media /var/www/html/m242/media

ln -s /var/www/html/m242/pub/static /var/www/html/m242/static

Comment: don't remove .htaccess file from pub/static Folder.

Comment: No, there is no need to remove .htaccess file from pub/static Folder.

Answer (score 0):

set base url in core_config_data in magento db -

UPDATE core_config_data SET value='http://localhost/magento242/pub/' WHERE path='web/unsecure/base_url';

This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

It seems now Magento will only load from pub folder. By default it will not be possible to load it from the root of Magento.

***So the best solution for this is to create a virtual host and point it to pub directory.***

**Alternative**

Meanwhile, as an alternative to run this on local machine I tried something else that seems to be working fine with the default setup. Like earlier we were using the `base_url` as `http://127.0.0.1/magento`. So instead of this now we need to use `http://127.0.0.1/magento/pub` as the `base_url`. Secure and Unsecure URL needs to be setup on the basis of this.

Setting this up will avoid the issue of 404 page coming.

Note: Verified this with the default Magento only. Not sure for the projects having much complex functionalities. But you can give this a try.

**We have another option without adding /pub follow below steps**

**1.** Copy .httaccess file from pub folder and override it to root .htaccess file

**2.** Upload pub/index.php file to root magento directory

**3.** Add below code in app/etc/env.php file

```
'system' => [
    'default' => [
        'web' => [
            'unsecure' => [
                'base_media_url' => '{{secure_base_url}}pub/media/',
                'base_static_url' => '{{secure_base_url}}pub/static/'
            ],
            'secure' => [
                'base_media_url' => '{{secure_base_url}}pub/media/',
                'base_static_url' => '{{secure_base_url}}pub/static/'
            ]
        ]
    ]
],
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to run commands for it. First upgrade command and then deploy.

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

It will generate the symlinks and you will see the proper ui of magento.

Thanks